# Trying to nest a horizontal recycleview into a vertical recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nested

I'm new to android, and trying to make a horizontal recycle view inside a vertical recycle view.

I've been following this blog :https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

But I think something is missing in my pj but couldn't figure it out. My app crashes when open.

Edit: so it doesn't crashe anymore but in the logcat it said :com.example.movie_ticket_booking E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

RecycleviewAdapter.java

```
  public class RecycleviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleviewAdapter.recycleviewHolder> {
        private final ArrayList<String> cinemalist;
        //private LayoutInflater inflateboss;
        private Context mcontext;
CinemashowtimeDataSource dataSource=CinemashowtimeDataSource.getInstance();
CinemaShowtimeRepository dataRepository=CinemaShowtimeRepository.getInstance(dataSource);
    Date startTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, 10, 30);
    List<Showtime> listTimes = dataRepository.getListShowtimes(startTime);

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public recycleviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View cinemaView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cinema_view,null);
        recycleviewHolder holder=new recycleviewHolder(cinemaView);
        //return new recycleviewHolder(cinemaView,this);
        return  holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull recycleviewHolder recycleviewHolder, int i) {
        String current=cinemalist.get(i);
        cinemaAdapter showlist= new cinemaAdapter(mcontext,listTimes);
        recycleviewHolder.recyclerchild.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mcontext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
        recycleviewHolder.recyclerchild.setAdapter(showlist);
        recycleviewHolder.cinema.setText(current);
        recycleviewHolder.recyclerchild.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cinemalist.size();
    }

    class recycleviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public final RecyclerView recyclerchild;
        public final TextView cinema;
        //final RecycleviewAdapter adapterboss;

        public recycleviewHolder(@NonNull View cinemaView){
            super((cinemaView));
            recyclerchild=cinemaView.findViewById(R.id.recyleview1);
            cinema=cinemaView.findViewById(R.id.cinemaName);
            //this.adapterboss=adapter;
        }
    }

    public RecycleviewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> cinema){
        this.cinemalist=cinema;
        this.mcontext=context;
        //inflateboss=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

}
```

cinemaAdapter.java

```
public class cinemaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<cinemaAdapter.cinemaViewHolder> {

    //private final ArrayList<String> cinemalist;    //test array
    private final List<Showtime> showtimelist;
    private LayoutInflater inflate;


    class cinemaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //public final TextView cinemaItemView;
        public final Button showButton;
        final cinemaAdapter madapter;

        public cinemaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,cinemaAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);
            //cinemaItemView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.word);
            showButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.showtime_button);
            this.madapter=adapter;
        }
    }
    /* TEST ADAPTER
    public cinemaAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> list){
        inflate=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cinemalist=list;
    }*/

    // NEW ADAPTER
    public cinemaAdapter(Context context, List<Showtime> showtimes){
        inflate=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.showtimelist=showtimes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public cinemaAdapter.cinemaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View cinemaView=inflate.inflate(R.layout.showtime_view,viewGroup,false);
        return new cinemaViewHolder(cinemaView,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull cinemaAdapter.cinemaViewHolder cinemaViewHolder, int i) {
        //String mcurrent=cinemalist.get(i);
        //cinemaViewHolder.cinemaItemView.setText(mcurrent);
        String mcurrent=String.format( "%d : %d",showtimelist.get(i).getTime().getHours(),showtimelist.get(i).getTime().getMinutes());
        cinemaViewHolder.showButton.setText(mcurrent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return cinemalist.size();
        return showtimelist.size();
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();;
    private final ArrayList<String> cinemalist=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;
    private cinemaAdapter madapter;
    private RecycleviewAdapter radapter;
    CinemashowtimeDataSource dataSource;
    CinemaShowtimeRepository dataRepository;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        //initial arraylist
        cinemalist.add("Cgv The Dark Kngiht");
        cinemalist.add("Cgv Avater");
        cinemalist.add("Cgv Star Wars");
        cinemalist.add("Cgv Avenger");
        cinemalist.add("Cgv Night crawler");
        cinemalist.add("Cgv Southpaw");

        //////////////////////////////////
        dataSource = CinemashowtimeDataSource.getInstance();
        dataRepository = CinemaShowtimeRepository.getInstance(dataSource);

        //    get the sample movie information data from data repository
        MovieInfo movie = dataRepository.getMovieInfo();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Movie title: %s", movie.getMovieTitle()));

        //    get list of date from data repository with start date. It will get 10 dates from dummy
        // data source
        Date startDate = new Date(2019, 05, 28);
        List<Date> listDates = dataRepository.getListDates(startDate);
        for (Date date : listDates) {
            Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    String.format("d/M/y = %d / %d / %d ;", date.getDate(), date.getMonth(), date.getYear()));
        }

        //    get list of showtimes from data repository with starting time. It will get 10 showtimes
        // from dummy data source
        Date startTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, 10, 30);
        List<Showtime> listTimes = dataRepository.getListShowtimes(startTime);

        //horizontal recycleview working
        //mRecycleView =findViewById(R.id.parent_recycleview);
        //madapter=new cinemaAdapter(this,listTimes);
        //mRecycleView.setAdapter(madapter);
        //mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));


        mRecycleView =findViewById(R.id.parent_recycleview);
        radapter=new RecycleviewAdapter(this,cinemalist);
        mRecycleView.setAdapter(madapter);
        mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));


        for (Showtime time : listTimes) {
            Log.d(
                    TAG,
                    String.format(
                            "h:m = %d : %d; is available = %b",
                            time.getTime().getHours(), time.getTime().getMinutes(), time.isAvailable()));
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/parent_recycleview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

cinemaview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cinemaName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CGV blah blah blah"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyleview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

showtime_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Button
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/showtime_button"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:text=""
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="auto"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: please share your crash logs

Comment: I'm sorry but how do i get the crash log from android studio

Comment: it said "2019-06-02 13:03:48.029 3030-3030/com.example.movie_ticket_booking E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"